# C++11 is not executing switch correctly when variable is declared in case block

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Consider the snippet below. If I compile this with GCC/C++11 then I expect that if I call this with e.g. `var=2` that that block is executed. Anyway I expect at least one of the 3 switch blocks are called.

However what I get is only the "start" and "end" lines.  **So this switch block is not working: even "default" is not called.** I even did not believe GDB when I saw this!

The root cause of this is the variable declaration in case block 1 (`int anotherVar`). To fix this problem I need to add brackets around case 1 (own scope) or decl the variable in the constructor body at the top.

My Questions are:

- Why is this happening? What is the technical reason? If this is not happening in all situations, then in which situations can this happen?
- Is there a compiler error/warning flag for this?

```
MyClass::MyClass(int var) { 
   std::cout << "Constructor start" << std::endl;
   switch (var) {
     case 1:
       std::cout << "Case 1 executed" << std::endl;
       int anotherVar = doSomething();
     case 2:
       std::cout << "Case 2 executed" <<std::endl;
     break;
     default:
       std:cout << "Default executed" << std::endl;
   }
   std::cout << "Constructor ended" << std::endl;
}`
```

This outputs when called with `var=2`:

```
Constructor start
Constructor ended
```

Comment: Could you pleasse post alll you code

Comment: Latest g++ does not compile your code as it is so it's better than a warning. Older g++ seem to require `-fpermissive` to compile this code.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: switch cases are mostly just labels (as for the ones used by `goto`), definition and usage of variable have some limitations with the goto/label (`int anotherVar` scope is not limited to `case 1`).

Comment: just a tip: change the line std::cout << "Constructor start" << std::endl; to std::cout << "Constructor start, var = "<< var << std::endl;

Answer (score 1):

This example is ill-formed, and should produce an error with a conforming compiler.

> **[stmt.dcl]/3** It is possible to transfer into a block, but not in a way that bypasses declarations with initialization. A program that jumps(91) from a point where a variable with automatic storage duration is not in scope to a point where it is in scope is ill-formed unless the variable has scalar type, class type with a trivial default constructor and a trivial destructor, a cv-qualified version of one of these types, or an array of one of the preceding types and is declared without an initializer (11.6).
>
> Footnote 91: The transfer from the condition of a `switch` statement to a `case` label is considered a jump in this respect.